# Quarkus provide redirect url if not authenticated

Tags: resteasy, quarkus, quarkus-qute

I am building out a web ui, and decided to get auth through jwt in a cookie.

I have gotten that bare minimum to work, but when I keep a page behind a role, the page (predictably) doesn't load. Rather than not loading, I would prefer to be able to tell the endpoint to redirect to the actual login page. Is this possible? Ideally I would be able to supply an annotation on the endpoint to say "go here if not auth'ed".

Code where I am setting up the web ui endpoints:

```
@Traced
@Slf4j
@Path("/")
@Tags({@Tag(name = "UI")})
@RequestScoped
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public class Index extends UiProvider {

    @Inject
    @Location("webui/pages/index")
    Template index;
    @Inject
    @Location("webui/pages/overview")
    Template overview;

    @Inject
    UserService userService;

    @Inject
    JsonWebToken jwt;

    @GET
    @PermitAll
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public TemplateInstance index(
            @Context SecurityContext securityContext
    ) {
        logRequestContext(jwt, securityContext);
        return index.instance();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("overview")
    @RolesAllowed("user")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public TemplateInstance overview(
            @Context SecurityContext securityContext
    ) {
        logRequestContext(jwt, securityContext);
        return overview.instance();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on how you want to handle the security and navigation.
If you use declarative RBAC(`@RolesAllowed`) than you can only control the response via JAXRS [ExceptionMapper](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/4.7.3.Final/userguide/html_single/#ExceptionMappers). You need to know the exception, that is thrown when the user does not have access to the required resources; for example in case user has valid token but does not satisfy `@RolesAllowed` constrain, then it would be `io.quarkus.security.ForbiddenException`, if he did not pass valid credentials, then `io.quarkus.security.UnauthorizedException`.

When you know the exception, you can define your ExceptionMapper(make sure you set the correct priority via `@Priority` as there might be other exception mappers on the classpath, e.g. those that Quarkus provides in dev mode).

The actual response handling depends on what the client is: if it is browser, then you probably want to return `303` or `302` redirect response with the `location` header containing your login URL so that the original request is redirected to login. An example for `UnauthorizedException`:

```java
import io.quarkus.security.UnauthorizedException;

import javax.annotation.Priority;
import javax.ws.rs.core.*;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider//register it as jaxrs provider
@Priority(1)//lower number-higher prio
//exception mappers are selected on best match for the exception class
//so make sure you find the particular exception you want to map
public class MyUnauthorizedExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<UnauthorizedException> { 
    @Context//you can inject JAXRS contextual resources here
    UriInfo crc;

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(UnauthorizedException exception) {
        System.out.println("User not authorized to access: " + crc.getRequestUri());
        return Response //seeOther = 303 redirect
                .seeOther(UriBuilder.fromUri("/someLogin")
                        //common pattern is to pass the original URL as param,
                        //so that after successful login, you redirect user back where he wanted
                        .queryParam("returnUrl", crc.getRequestUri())
                        .build())//build the URL where you want to redirect
                .entity("Not authorized")//entity is not required
                .build();
    }
}
```

Other option is, that you handle the authentication programmatically inside your endpoint, checking the `Principal` or current `JWTToken` for required attributes and, if not sufficient, return the corresponding `Response` e.g. `return Response.seeOther("/login")`.

This should work, but may cause issues if your client is for example some javascript code, doing POST requests. In general, you might be better off serving your UI from a dedicated server, using Quarkus as API endpoint provider, communicating via HTTP/REST between your UI and BE. That way you have way more control over the behavior.

Comment: This is what I ended up implemented, wishing there might be an easier way like an annotation but this works. Thanks!